TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'
I'm using tesseract.js in the Angular application I'm working on. I have no issue running the application but whenever I run the test, I keep getting the below error:
Error: node_modules/tesseract.js/src/index.d.ts:160:60 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig. 160     | CanvasRenderingContext2D | File | Blob | ImageData | Buffer | OffscreenCanvas;

I tried running "npm install --save @types/node" and adding types:["node"] in tsconfig.spec.json but it didn't resolve the issue instead the components are no longer getting recognized.
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) AppComponent should render title FAILED
    Error: NG0304: 'lp-header' is not a known element (used in the 'AppComponent' component template):
    1. If 'lp-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
    2. If 'lp-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.



import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    })
  );

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span')?.textContent).toContain(
      'logan-gwa-calculator app is running!'
    );
  });
});




The two errors you are showing are unrelated to one another. The second message is saying that you didn't import the components properly into your spec file. Please share your spec file.

I'm only getting the second error whenever I add "node" in the types as an attempt to fix the first error.

You need to import everything that your AppComponent uses, so whatever module lp-header is apart of, you need to import that into the test. I would try not to use declarations in the test if you can, and just import standalone components and modules.
